# Wit.ai bot doesn’t recognise the pre-defined entity location value when requesting from external app

Tags: node.js, wit.ai

The Wit.ai bot doesn’t recognise the pre-defined entity location value when requesting from external node app, using get/message. (It shows intent, doesn’t show the location value). Same with with post/converse: very low confidence 0,2-0,4, entities not recognised.

Server deployed on heroku.
When tested in the wit stories, bot recognition works.
What can be the reason for wit not recognising entities?

I’m making request with Fetch:

```js
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    const message = req.body.message
    const sessionId = req.body.sessionId
    fetch(witUrl+'/message?v=20170611&session_id='+sessionId+'&q='+message, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        }
    })
        .then(r=> r.json())
        .then(j =>
    res.send(j)
    )
    .catch(e=> console.log('error in fetch with wit',e))

});
```

Thanks,

Comment: Regenerate your API key, you've just exposed it to everyone.